# Why can't argument type 'JsObject' be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I've been programming in Flutter for a couple of weeks. Now I need after a login connection with te database to go to another page. The connection works and the problem lays with het navigator.push().

I tried te use te navigator.push() method, but it seems that te 'context' doesn't work.
My question, does anyone have a idea how to fix it or a different method to navigate to another page?

If I hover over the error it shows the following problem: The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'paginaqr.dart';

Future loginApi() async {
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      "url",
      body: {
        'inlognaam': inlognaam.text,
        'wachtwoord': wachtwoord.text,
      });
      final String inloggen = jsonDecode(response.body) as String;
      if(inloggen == 'true'){
        print(response.body);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute<dynamics>(builder: (context) => paginaqr()),
        );
//        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute<dynamics>(builder: (BuildContext context) => paginaqr()));
//        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');

      } else{

      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste your imports?

Comment: These are my imports:

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'paginaqr.dart';

Comment: remove the `import 'dart:js';`

Comment: A it works, thank you for your quick reaction!

Comment: @David I have the same issue , any progress ? , removing dart.js didnt help

Comment: @MohamedElShenawy removing the 'dart:js'; wort for me, so I didn't looked more into it, so sorry I can't help you

Comment: @David thanks man for he reply anyway , It tended to be a different  issue at my side as I used a stateless widget instead of stateful widget , and for some reason it generated that error